# Description: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Layout_1.enter. Location: Version2CaseStudy/Main/exitGL_Main - Exit

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to link the enter exit blocks (exit is in Main & enter is in an agent Layout_1 within Main) but I get the error :
"Description: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Layout_1.enter. Location: Version2CaseStudy/Main/exitGL_Main - Exit"

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I was calling the Layout_1 and not layout_1

Comment: Great. Now also check the search, this error has been asked about many times before (for good reason, it is not trivial to understand). Any other questions, feel free to ask, here is some guidance for AnyLogic users: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

just to explain a bit

A static variable has to be defined as such, and the purpose of it, is to be a variable that is associated to the class, and not the instance of that class.

In AnyLogic from a beginner perspective you have:
A class, or an Agent type, which by convention has a name that starts with a capital letter, such as Layout
An instance of that class, or an agent from the population, which by convention is defined with a lowercase letter such as layout
A list or a population of agents, which is defined with a lower case but it's plural, such as layouts

when a variable is static and you do Layout.variable=x, you are changing the value of that variable for all instances of that class or agent type
When you do do layout.variable=x (not static), you are changing the variable value for the instance of that class, or for an agent of the population.

if you have a variable that is NOT static, and you dare doing Layout.variable you will get this error... because the variable is not defined as static, you cannot access it with Layout (upper case L)

In general you will know that this error occurs when you tried to access a variable using the class or agent type (uppercase first letter) since AnyLogic by default doesn't allow you to create static variables, so it's almost certain that you made this mistake.